# Can i pass the trying part in try/except blocks if there is an error?

Tags: python

I have a function and it prints things but this function gets an error for some values. So I used a try/except block to solve this but even if the fuction gets an error it keeps printing until the error. The function looks like this:

```
def error_solver(x):
    try:
        function(x)
    except:
        error_solver(x+1)

error_solver(0)
```

If you can't understand what I'm talking about here is another example:

```
def f(x):
    try:
        function_1()
        function_2()
    except:
        pass
```

Let's say an error occurs in function_2(). In this case if function_1() works without errors it will be executed. I don't want this to happen and just end the fuction without executing the first function. How can i solve this problem?

Comment: So you want to run the functions (the only way to know if there is an exception) without running the functions?

Comment: You can't *not* execute `function_1` after it's already been executed. The only thing you can do is undo whatever *effect* `function_1` might have had, or make the effect in a temporary location which will be copied into the real "target" after `function_2` succeeds (think database transactions).

Comment: Also, `error_solver` and `f` do two completely different things; I don't see what the comparison between them is.

Comment: You could return the output instead of printing it in `function_1` and print it as the last action in the `try` block, but if it's possible depends on the output.

Comment: ‘So you want to run the functions (the only way to know if there is an exception) without running the functions?’ 

Yes

Comment: chepner my function is a recursive function and after some values it gives me an error thats why I wanted to give another example. The second example kind of simplifies my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prevent leaving a halfway through try - except block by either restoring the system to either a previous, or a well known state, or by buffering the result of the try block, and only applying the result at the end of the try block.

If the only thing done by your functions is printing, then the last method might  make sense:

Instead of printing to the screen, you could print to a string, and only at the end print the resulting string to the screen. For this to work, you will have to modify `function_1()` and `function_2()` to take a `file` argument:

```
import io, sys

def function_1(file):
  print("hi from function_1", file=file)

def function_2(file):
  print("hi from function_2", file=file)

def f(x):
  try:
    with io.StringIO() as file:
      function_1(file)
      function_2(file)
      sys.stdout.write(file.getvalue())
  except:
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example `function_1` will always execute before `function_2`, regardless if `function_2` fails or not. If you need your `function_1(); function_2()` operation to be transactional (both succeed or nothing happens), you can add an explicit undo operation:

```py
def f(x):
    try:
        function_1()
        function_2()
    except Function2Error:
        undo_function_1()
```

Answer (score -1):

Python will execute all the lines till it reaches the error line. So we can't undo the operations that executed in function_1.